# Серверная отправка файла по cURL

Tags: php, curl

На сервере есть 3 файла:

- sender.php - отправитель файла
- reciever.php - получатель файла
- forSend/img.jpg - файл для отправки

`sender.php` должен отправить файл `forSend/img.jpg` на `reciever.php`, получить ответ от ресивера и показать его на экран.

***sender.php***

```
<?php 

$server = 'http://192.168.56.101/reciever.php';

$curl = curl_init($server);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
$fileLocation = realpath(getcwd().'/forSend/img.jpg');
echo 'is real file:';
var_dump(is_file($fileLocation));
$data = array(
    'file' => "@{$fileLocation}",
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
echo '<br><b>RESPONSE</b><br>';
if (curl_errno($curl)){
    echo '<span style="color:red">';
    echo curl_error($curl);
    echo '</span>';
} else {
    echo '<span style="color:green">';
    echo $response;
    echo '</span>';
}
curl_close($curl);
```

***reciever.php***

```
<?php

echo var_dump($_FILES);
```

Вывод после запроса:

```
is real file:bool(true) 
RESPONSE
array(0) { }
```

Как же передать файл forSend/img.jpg через cURL?

UPD1:

*var_dump($_POST)*

> array(1) { ["file"]=> string(38)
>   "@/usr/share/nginx/html/forSend/img.jpg" }

*var_dump($_FILES)*

> array(0) { }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На текущий момент отправка файлов через `@` является `deprecated`, и в новых версиях отключена по умолчанию. Следует использовать `CURLFile`, попробуйте код представленный ниже, возможно это решит вашу проблему.

```
$data = array(
    'file' => new CURLFile($fileLocation,'image/jpeg','img')
);
```

Comment: Добавлю что mime-тип для изображения можно получить так: $image_mime = image_type_to_mime_type(exif_imagetype($file));

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
$data = array(
'file' => "@${fileLocation}",
);
```

или

```
$data = array(
 'file' => "@" . $fileLocation,
);
```

Comment: Содержимое массива $data остается неизменным.  ["file"]=> string(38) "@/usr/share/nginx/html/forSend/img.jpg" Т.е. файл так же не отправляется

Comment: @atom-22 В новых версия PHP знак @ не работает. Его поддержку можно включить следующим образом: `curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, false);`